# How to fix jQuery media query that works with console.log() but not proper code

Tags: jquery, media-queries

I am trying to change the background image of an element based on screen width and the reason I can't use CSS is because the image path is pulled in to the template using PHP.

I have tried several different methods of jQuery media query and the method I am using now does work because I added different messages inside console.log() and these displayed correctly.

When I replace the `console.log()` with the code for changing the image, it doesn't work.

```js
var image;
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
  if (jQuery(window).width() <= 800) {
    var image = '<?php the_field("mobile_header_background"); ?>';
    var css = 'url(' + image + ') no-repeat center;';
    jQuery('.homehead').css("background", css);
  } else {
    var image = '<?php the_field("header_background"); ?>';
    var css = 'url(' + image + ') no-repeat center;';
    jQuery('.homehead').css("background", css);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="homehead" style="background: url() no-repeat center; background-size: cover;">
```

I expect the background value of the homehead div to update accordingly but it's just not working.

Edit:

I have just tried simplifying the code a bit removing the need for variables and outputting the image path straight in to the .css function but this also didn't work despite outputting the image path correctly.

```js
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
  if (jQuery(window).width() <= 800) {
    jQuery(".homehead").css("background-image","url(<?php the_field('mobile_header_background'); ?>)");
  } else {
    jQuery(".homehead").css("background-image","url(<?php the_field('header_background'); ?>)");
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="homehead" style="background-image: url(); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; background-size: cover;">
```

Comment: You can't put insert php code in javascript. PHP code has to be run on the server, before the page gets sent to the client

Comment: @yts The PHP code isn't the issue because when I look at the syntax on the front end, the path to the image is in the script as it should be, so that line is working fine.

Comment: Oh. If this is in a script tag in the PHP file then that would makes sense. I was assuming it was in a static JS file being called in.

Comment: @yts Yes this is a custom Wordpress theme so is a PHP header template pulling in the image path from a custom field that returns the URL.

Comment: Did you try putting debuggers in your code? Anything fire when you resize the browser? You should be able to see what's happening there

Comment: @yts i've just added `console.log(image);` which output the path to the image correctly and then `console.log(css);` which output the CSS property correctly, so do I assume from this that it's the last line that has the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that jQuery is ignoring the css setting because they don't like the syntax. If you remove the semicolon from the end of the css string, like

```
var css = 'url(' + image + ') no-repeat center';
```

instead of

```
var css = 'url(' + image + ') no-repeat center;';
```

it should work.

Just keep in mind that this code will only run on resize. You may want to run it on page load as well. I'd suggest moving the code into a named function and calling that on load, as well as passing it into the `resize` handler.

Comment: @Adrian Strange.. I tried it out on a website using jQuery and that part of the code didn't work with the semicolon but did work after I removed it. So you definitely want to remove the semicolons from the string (inside the string, not the one after it).

Comment: have just updated question with another method I tried